# Telnet byusing Shellscript (OSX)

Tags: macos, shell

I want to connect the machine by telnet and tell the command.
How I should write the code?
There is no username and password.
I'm using OSX.

The code below doesn't work.

test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
sh /Users/hoge/Desktop/cmds.sh | telnet 192.168.1.2 5024 >> auto-telnet.log
```

cmds.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 30; echo command
sleep 5; echo exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got correct code!

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 20
set address "my_machine_ip"
set port "23"

spawn telnet $address $port
expect "$" { sleep 30; send "command\r"; }
expect "$" { sleep 5; send "exit\r"; }
expect eof
```